# How to remove React Auth in Laravel 6.0 in CMD?

Tags: reactjs, laravel, authentication

Sorry, I've tried to search on the answer for the command on CLI to remove the react auth that I downloaded.

I also tried looking in the documentation on "Laravel 6.0.", then look for similar keywords on searching such as reset, remove, react yet, seems there is no relative solution, or probably my fault to not find the right solution.

Can someone help me solve this problem?
Thank you.

Comment: You need to remove the generated auth with the react template?

Comment: Yes @loic.lopez, how is it possible?

Comment: Are you using `laravel/ui`?

Comment: Yes @loic.lopez, I used that command.

Comment: I appreciate your quick response. :D

Comment: Do you want to switch to vue for exemple or just remove the template?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't want to use any front-end framework yet. My goal is to remove the framework which were installed. I'll try to look for this solution. If you're busy you can do your thing. :D Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**From the 5.8 Laravel documentation: [laravel.com/docs/5.8/frontend](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/frontend)**

> Removing The Frontend Scaffolding
>
> If you would like to remove the frontend scaffolding from your
>   application, you may use the preset Artisan command. This command,
>   when combined with the none option, will remove the Bootstrap and Vue
>   scaffolding from your application, leaving only a blank SASS file and
>   a few common JavaScript utility libraries:

```sh
php artisan preset none
```

So try with laravel 6.x:

```sh
php artisan ui none
```

Comment: Sorry for late response. I've solve this a month ago. Your solution is correct.

Thank you.